# A minor issue on the proof of "if (L',D') is easy, then so is (L,D)" in Average-case Complexity!

Tags: complexity-theory, average-case

In Arora and Barak's textbook, in chapter 18, p.366-367, they prove the following theorem:

> Theorem 18.7 if $(L,D)$ is reduced to $(L',D')$ and $(L',D') \in disP$, then $(L,D) \in disP$

The proof goes by just following the definition of average-case reduction and disP. I.e., suppose there is an efficient algorithm $A'$ for $(L',D')$. Then there exists constants $C$ and $\epsilon$ such that for every m,
$E[\frac{time_{A'}(D'_m)^\epsilon}{m}] \leq C$. Let f be the reduction from $(L,D)$ to $(L',D')$ and let $A$ be the algorithm for deciding $L$. That is, given input $x$, it computes $f(x)$ and then outputs $A'(f(x))$. Since $A$ decides $L$, all that is left to show is that $A$ runs in time-polynomial on the average with respect to the distribution $D$.

For simplicity, assume that for every $x$, $|f(x)| = |x|^d$ and the computing $f$ on length n inputs is faster than the running time of A' on length n^d inputs and hence $time_A(x) \leq 2 time_{A'}(f(x))$."

I don't know how this sentence "$|f(x)| = |x|^d$ and the computing $f$ on length n inputs is faster than the running time of $A'$ on length $n^d$ inputs" **implies** $time_A(x) \leq 2 time_{A'}(f(x))$?. for example, where does 2 came from?